# RabbitMQ Queue organisation

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a single rabbitmq server but some of my queues are logically grouped together on that server.

Is it possible to organize queues into some type of folder structure or in any other way in the management portal so it represents those logical groups ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use prefixes for queues name for that. Alternatively, if they depends on the same exchange(s) and that exchange(s) used only by them, then moving whole bunch of queues and exchange to separate vhost may be a solution. But usually prefixes works well.